# How to wrap deferred function which returns promise so outer function returns real value not a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have deferred function which returns promise for example

```
function promiseAddition(x,y){
 var defer = deferred();
 // code
 returns defer.promise;
}
```

I need to to call this function inside outer function and returns result of addition (value not a promise).
How to achieve this ? I am using deferred module from node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to to call this function [from somewhere] and return [a] result […] value [that is] not a promise

You cannot. If a value is wrapped in a promise once, it and all the values depending on it will be wrapped in promises forever.

If you are using promises to represent asynchronous results, then it simply is impossible to extract the value - which is not yet there.

Of course various types of promises do allow to extract values, but usually only under certain circumstances - for example, a callback in the future. However, for a *transformation* (as is an addition) you will need to return another promise. Use its `then` method for that purpose.

Comment: This is correct. The whole idea of "deferred" is that it is deferred! In order to return the value you want straight from a function that function would have to wait for the logic to be complete. Since the whole point is to defer execution and only return a "promise to do it later" there is no way for you to get that data back out and return it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If function you're wrapping is returning promise which has not been resolved yet, then as Bergi pointed you can't return resolved value directly, as value is not there yet.

However, if it's about wrapping function that returns promise which in all cases is resolved, then when using [deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred), you can easily configure such wrapper:

```
var getOutOfPromise = function () {
  var value;
  resolvedPromise.done(function (result) { value = result; });
  return value;
};
```

Still, recommended way is not to unwrap promises, but work with them, pass them across the functions and let them unwrap values whenever they need.
 If you're working with implementation that has `promise.done` and provides sync access to resolved value, there's no added cost.